# Converting one Spark dataframe to another with a different schema

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to convert a particular (py)spark dataframe into another; the original has the following fields:

['ID', 'event', 'tstamp']

Let's say there's m distinct possible events that can appear in the 'event' column, denoted by'event_i', i = 1,..m. What I'd like to create is a new dataframe with the following fields:

['ID', 'event_1', 'event_2', 'event_3', ...'event_m'],

where for each unique ID, I have the number of counts for each of the m events that occurred. Is there a straightforward way to do this using only the spark SQL API, that doesn't require converting to RDDs and back?

I can create a dataframe from scratch by first creating a schema with the m events, filter by each unique ID, and then use groupBy('event').count() to get the event counts and manually create rows from this and append them to the dataframe, but I just get this feeling that there's probably an easier way to do this..I couldn't find anything like this on SO, but apologies if this has already been asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution could be using .withColumn method and UDF to generate a new DF with a new columns, like this way

```
val myudf1 = udf((event: String) => if(event == "event_1") 1 else 0 )
val myudf2 = udf((event: String) => if(event == "event_2") 1 else 0 )
....

val countersDF = df.withColumn("event_1", myudf1(df("event")))
  .withColumn("event_2", myudf2(df("event")))
  .withColumn("event_3", myudf3(df("event")))
...
```

Obviously you can automate more my code, just an example.
At this point you should group over your ID and perform sum aggregation.

```
countersDF.groupBy("ID").agg(sum("event_1"), sum("event_2"), ...)
```

Comment: aha, that's clever! Much better than iteratively going through each unique ID and creating rows, thanks!!